# Problem with sorting NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsdictionary

I need to sort a NSDictionary of dictionaries. It looks like:

```
{//dictionary
        RU = "110.1"; //key and value
        SG = "150.2"; //key and value
        US = "50.3"; //key and value
    }
```

Result need to be like:

```
 {//dictionary
            SG = "150.2"; //key and value
            RU = "110.1"; //key and value
            US = "50.3"; //key and value
        }
```

I am trying this:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (sorting)

-(NSMutableDictionary*)sortDictionary
{
    NSArray *allKeys = [self allKeys];
    NSMutableArray *allValues = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *sortValues= [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *sortKeys= [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i=0;i<[[self allValues] count];i++)
    {
        [allValues addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[self allValues] objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]]];   
    }



    [sortValues addObjectsFromArray:allValues];
    [sortKeys addObjectsFromArray:[self allKeys]];
    [sortValues sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floatValue" ascending:NO] autorelease]]];

    for(int i=0;i<[sortValues count];i++)
    {
        [sortKeys replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[allKeys objectAtIndex:[allValues indexOfObject:[sortValues objectAtIndex:i]]]];
        [allValues replaceObjectAtIndex:[allValues indexOfObject:[sortValues objectAtIndex:i]] withObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", sortKeys);
    NSLog(@"%@", sortValues);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:sortValues forKeys:sortKeys]);
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:sortValues forKeys:sortKeys];
}

@end
```

This is the result of NSLog:
1)

```
{
SG,
RU,
US
}
```

2)

```
{
150.2,
110.1,
50.3
}
```

3)

```
{
            RU = "110.1";
            SG = "150.2";
            US = "50.3";
        }
```

Why is this happening? Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

`NSDictionary` are unsorted by nature. The order of the objects as retrieved by `allKeys` and `allValues` will always be undetermined. Even if you reverse engineer the order it may still change in the next system update.

There is however more powerful alternatives to `allKeys` that are used to retrieve the keys in a defined and predictable order:

- `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` - Useful for sorting in ascending order according to the `compare:` method of the value objects.
- `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` - New in iOS 4, use a block to do the sort inline.

Answer (score 2):

WOW. Thanx, PeyloW! It's what i needed! I also find this code and it helps me to reorder results:

```
@implementation NSString (numericComparison)

- (NSComparisonResult) floatCompare:(NSString *) other
{
    float myValue = [self floatValue];
    float otherValue = [other floatValue];
    if (myValue == otherValue) return NSOrderedSame;
    return (myValue < otherValue ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending);
}

- (NSComparisonResult) intCompare:(NSString *) other
{
    int myValue = [self intValue];
    int otherValue = [other intValue];
    if (myValue == otherValue) return NSOrderedSame;
    return (myValue < otherValue ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending);
}

@end
```

Comment: My pleasure. Don't forget to accept the answer you deem correct. Helps other users when searching for answers, and good for my ego :).

Answer (score 1):

a NSDictionary is not ordened, so it doens't matter in what order you construct a NSDIctionary.

a NSArray is ordened. If you want to have the NSDictionary ordened in memory, you should somehow make a NSArray of key value pairs. You can also return two NSArrays with corresponding indeces.

If you only want to iterate over the elements way, you can iterate over a sorted array of keys (this is what koregan suggests).